# Conditionally Delete in Ant

Tags: java, ant, conditional-statements

I want to delete the directory if the property "delete-compiled-dir" is set to true. If the property is false then do not execute it. Right now I have

```
<target name="deleted-after-compilation" depends="compile,jar">
        <condition property="${delete-compiled-dir}" value="true">
            <delete dir="${compilation-dir}" />
        </condition>
            <echo> Deleting Compiled Directory Classes </echo>
    </target>
```

I get the error message :

```
condition doesn't support the nested "delete" element.
```

Comment: What is the question ? Are you having any issues ?

Comment: Yes. The condition apparently doesn't support delete element.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the condition to your target using `if` (see [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)).

The target will only be executed when the property `compilation-dir` is set (to any value, e.g. `false`).

```
<target name="deleted-after-compilation" depends="compile,jar"
        if="${compilation-dir}">
    <delete dir="${compilation-dir}" />
    <echo> Deleting Compiled Directory Classes </echo>
</target>
```

---

To only execute it when a property is set to `true`, you need to set another property first and check this one in the `if`. You could add both as dependency the another target:

```
<target name="set-delete-property">
    <condition property="delete-compilation-dir">
        <istrue value="${compilation-dir}"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="deleted-after-compilation"
      depends="compile,jar" if="${compilation-dir}">
    ....

<target name="some-target"
      depends="set-delete-property,deleted-after-compilation">
</target>
```

Comment: I don't want it to execute if the the property is false.

Comment: (I can't test it at the moment, but it should work like that)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this:

### Use *conditions* on the target entity

Targets can contain `if` and `unless` conditions. The target will execute depending whether or not the property is set. (Not set to *true*, just set). This is a common way to see if you need to do something or not:

```
<target name="deleted.after.compilation" 
    if="delete.compiled.dir"
    depends="jar">
        <delete dir="${compilation-dir}" />
        <echo> Deleting Compiled Directory Classes </echo>
</target>
```

You can set the property on the command line:

```
$ ant -Ddelete.compiled.dir all
```

Note: I use periods as separators for the names of properties and targets. Also note that I only depend upon the target `jar` since `jar` is also dependent upon `compile`, there's no need to have them both.

### Use Ant's 1.9.1 *conditional clauses*

As of Ant 1.9.1, Ant has [conditional attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) that can be added to tasks. You need to add a *Namepsace declaration* in your `<project>` entity:

```
<project ... 
    xmlns:if="ant:if"
    xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

    <target name="deleted.after.compilation" 
        depends="jar">
        <delete dir="${compilation-dir}" if:true="${delete.compiled.dir}"/>
        <echo if:true="${delete.compiled.dir}"> Deleting Compiled Directory Classes </echo>
    </target>
```

### Use Ant-Contrib's [If Statement](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Ha ha, that wacky Ant-Contrib library. No one knows who maintains it, and it hasn't been touched in years, but many people depend so heavily on it.

```
<project ...>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${ivy.dir}/antcontrib">
                <include name="ant-contrib*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="deleted.after.compilation" 
        depends="jar">
        <if>
            <istrue value="${delete.compiled.dir}"/>
            <then>
                <delete dir="${compilation-dir}"/>
                <echo>Deleting Compiled Directory Classes </echo>
            </then?
        </if>
    </target>
```

You can see why Ant-Contrib is popular. It contains a lot of power, and we all know it. Plus, if someone is still using Ant 1.8 or 1.7, this will still work.

Answer (score 1):

As of Ant 1.9.1, you can use conditionals on any task.  Described [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html).

Add this namespace to your project element:

```
<project name="yourproject" xmlns:if="ant:if">
```

Then add this to your delete:

```
<delete dir="${compilation-dir}" if:true="${delete-compiled-dir}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have get the property ,you can just use it in a target.

```
<target name="delete" if="${delete-compiled-dir}">
    <delete dir="${compilation-dir}" />
</target>
```